# Miragejs: Unable to load the ionic icons - data:image/svg+xml

Tags: ionic-framework, mocking, miragejs

Getting below error in the browser console and the icons are not getting rendered.

```
Object { description: "Mirage: undefined", fileName: "http://localhost:8100/js/chunk-vendors.js line 2021 > eval", lineNumber: 806,
message: "Mirage: Your app tried to GET 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='ionicon' viewBox='0 0 512 512'><title>Person</title><path d='M332.64 64.58C313.18 43.57 286 32 256 32c-30.16 0-57.43 11.5-76.8 32.38-19.58 21.11-29.12 49.8-26.88 80.78C156.76 206.28 203.27 256 256 256s99.16-49.71 103.67-110.82c2.27-30.7-7.33-59.33-27.03-80.6zM432 480H80a31 31 0 01-24.2-11.13c-6.5-7.77-9.12-18.38-7.18-29.11C57.06 392.94 83.4 353.61 124.8 326c36.78-24.51 83.37-38 131.2-38s94.42 13.5 131.2 38c41.4 27.6 67.74 66.93 76.18 113.75 1.94 10.73-.68 21.34-7.18 29.11A31 31 0 01432 480z'/></svg>',
but there was no route defined to handle this request.
Define a route for this endpoint in your routes() config.
Did you forget to define a namespace?", name: "Error", number: undefined, stack: "Mirage: MirageError@webpack-internal:///.
```

Tried to add `this.passthrough();` and combination of it, couldn't help any of those. It's working for API calls but not for this particular case, I meant the icons not getting rendered.

How can we ignore/passthrough the requests for `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,...`?

Comment: Please let me know if my comment solve your issue and mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same issue. You can solve that error if you add this configuration to allow loading base64 images like svgs:

```js
new Server({
  routes() {

    this.pretender.get('data:image/*', this.pretender.passthrough);
  }
});
```

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Thank you for this! I ran into the same issue with the "system" icons from [Shoelace](https://shoelace.style/components/icon/) which use embedded SVG data URLs as well.